Expo React Native Web Deployment: Use dist as the Publish Directory and npx expo export --platform web as the Build Command
I've spent the last 2 days trying to get my Expo React Native project to publish correctly on web hosting platforms like Netlify, Vercel, Railway and Render. After a lot of trial and error, here’s what I found:
1- Publish Directory should be set to dist. Using web-build as the publish directory no longer works, as Expo doesn't output to that folder anymore.
2- Build Command should be npx expo export --platform web. Don't use npx expo export:web or expo build:web, as they’re no longer valid for the latest Expo versions.
The frustrating part is that there’s almost no documentation online mentioning these changes, and even when an error occurs during the build, the terminal suggests the outdated commands (npx expo export:web and web-build) – which are incorrect!
I hope this saves someone else from spending days trying to get this to work. If anyone has insights on why this change hasn’t been documented or if there’s something I missed, please share!

You can deploy your project on Vercel. Under Build & Development Settings set the following options:

Framework preset: Other
Build command: npx expo export -p web
Output directory: dist
install command: npm install or yarn install

